# Examples of IPAddress that are not in AddressFamily InterNetwork

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sockets

I want to add some unit tests around some legacy code that retrieves a collection of IPAddress objects.  The code skips any where `ip.Address.AddressFamily != System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork`.

For the purpose of my test I want to construct an IPAddress that matches this condition.

I'm only familiar with IPv4: AddressFamily enumerates lots of other interesting protocols like Chaos, Pup and DataKit. I've tried Googling these for a while but can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the reference source code for IPAddress](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs).  It turns out it only handles ipv4 and ipv6 addresses anyway.

So for my test, all I had to do was supply an ipv6 address:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("2607:f0d0:1002:0051:0000:0000:0000:0004");
```